# Trying to install poppler-utils - package not found on linux

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, ubuntu, poppler

I'm trying to: apt-get install poppler-utils

And I get error of:  Unable to locate package poppler-utils.

I searched for the package inside https://packages.ubuntu.com/ , but even there i can't find him. How do I install poppler-utils then to keep working with other libraries which needs this dependency? For example spatie/pdf-to-text.

System version: Version: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Running inside: Docker container

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Laravel or Docker in any way?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm installing it inside docker container, want to work with a laravel package, just that way.

Comment: Version: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Comment: Did you try running `apt update` before searching?

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers of `apt` using systems such as Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, and so on usually don't have the package lists required for `apt` when they run. This is intentional so that people will get the up to date package list after the initiation. So in order to install or search any app in those containers you must first `apt update`.